# Android AlarmManager после перезагрузки

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver, android-alarm-manager

Нужно, чтобы `AlarmManager` срабатывал в определенное время. Если телефон не перезагружать, то всё проходит гладко (допустим, поставил на 6 вечера, то он срабатывает в 6 вечера). Если перезагрузить, вставить в манифест

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>`

`<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

то он сработает мгновенно после перезагрузки, без - вообще не срабатывает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно еще в коде прописать.
Обычно выглядит так:
В манифесте

```
    <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

В коде

```
public class BootReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
// запускаем аларм
}
}
```

Comment: Заново в ресивере установить будильник?  Т.е. система такая: Без перезагрузки - просто в рандомном классе устанавливаю алярм на этот ресивер, при перезагрузке - устанавливаю алярм, он запускает ресивер, в этом же ресивере снова устанавливаю будильник?